# Base Class properties not written to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.0, salat

Using Play 2 / Scala , casbah and Salat

```
abstract class BaseQuestion(val data:String,val responses:List[StudentResponse] = Nil){
  val key:String = UUID.randomUUID().toString
}

case class Question(override val data:String, val questionType:String = "MCQ", val choices:List[String] = Nil,
                    val answer:String,override val responses:List[StudentResponse])
  extends BaseQuestion(data = data,responses = responses)
```

However when I use [SalatDAO.save](https://github.com/novus/salat/wiki/SalatDAO), and check the mongo database the property key is not being stored in the Mongo database Object.

Not sure what the problem is.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to annotate property `key` with `@Persist`

https://github.com/novus/salat/wiki/Annotations